# Which Linux distribution comes with a gcc of 4.3.4?

Tags: linux, matlab, gcc, version

Simply need a gcc of 4.3.4 version to compile some mex for MATLAB?
Couldn't find one in my sourselist.
I guess I need a distribution with a gcc of exact that version.

MATLAB R2011a tells me that 4.3.4 is needed.
Currently I have a higher version of gcc and it does not work for MATLAB.
All gcc versions in my sourselist are too high.
And I don't think it would work if the version is lower.
So I need exactly that version.

Comment: Or just download that version and install it?

Comment: Not to mention, why do you think you need that exact version?

Comment: I try to compile gcc 4.3.4 myself and come into a lot of trouble installing prerequisite.

Comment: It just do not work with the current version I have.

Comment: You need a version that uses the same ABI, not that version specifically.

Comment: Maybe it is time to **try Scilab** (Scilab is a free software equivalent of Matlab see http://scilab.org/ for more)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to http://distrowatch.com/. It lists the latest distributions along with the package versions it comes with. Select the one you need